# git svn clone not checking out all directories

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I have a project in SVN and I tried to clone it with git-svn. I followed the example in the [git-svn docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn).

```
git svn clone  svn+ssh://host/path/trunk  project_name
```

The command completed with no error msg, but the cloned project does not contain all the directories as the project in SVN.

At the top level, my SVN project has...

```
$ svn ls  svn+ssh://host/path/trunk
README
Rakefile
app/
config/
db/
doc/
lib/
log/
public/
script/
test/
tmp/
vendor/
```

After cloning, locally I have...

```
README
Rakefile
app
config
doc
public
script
test
```

There are also subdirs missing.

---

UPDATE

Experimentally cloned another project on same host. Seemed to work fine. What's special about this one? Nothing I can think of except that I just created it and imported it into SVN before cloning. Would that make a difference?

---

Tried creating a completely new project, importing to SVN and cloning. Got same result, same missing dirs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I can tell, git doesn't tracks empty directories:

http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/GitFaq#CanIaddemptydirectories.3F:

> That is, directories never have to be added to the repository, and are not tracked on their own.

Does this make sense? Are the missing directories empty?

Comment: Yes, it was the empty directories that were not pulled in from SVN. Thanks.

Comment: I had a similar problem.  According to the link, Git doesn't actually track directories.  It tracks files.  So, no files in a directory means Git doesn't know about it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your SVN is not using some [**svn:external**](http://www.simplisticcomplexity.com/2008/03/05/cleanly-migrate-your-subversion-repository-to-a-git-repository/) (see comments)?
More details on that process in the article ["moving from svn to git"](http://www.ultrasaurus.com/sarahblog/2009/02/moving-from-svn-to-git/)

> `svn-git` really ought to warn you somehow that it doesn’t support fetching externals.
>   This I learned by noticing that the `svn log` had no checkins of those files and then saw when I did a clean `svn checkout` that it was fetching externals for the vendor/plugins directory.
>
> So, I decided to just pull in the vendor/plugins directory verbatim, detaching the external reference, and move to git submodules as we upgrade.
>   What I really wanted to do, but didn’t see how to, was to reference the plugin code as an http URL and keep as a submodule, so that I would have a handy reference to source location and revision

Comment: Thanks. I'm 100% sure that's not happening here. I'll check out the link.

Comment: @Ethan: all right, I leave the post for information. You can post your own answer if you find the root cause, and select it as the official one.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I need to do some reading and gain a better general understanding of how git works.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

[svn2git](http://github.com/iteman/svn2git/tree/master)

or

```
git svn clone  svn+ssh://host/path project_name --trunk=trunk/*
```

There is some form of deep cloning in git 1.6+, but I'm not sure if this is the right syntax

Comment: Thanks. I checked out svn2git on Github. I'll try it when I can.